# How do I programmatically create a list of new users?

Tags: 7, drush

I'm trying to use the following drush script, but I keep getting errors. Currently, it is not properly setting the user role to Premium.

```
#!/user/bin/env drush
<?php  
  $users = [ 
      "name" => "email",
      "name" => "email",
      "name" => "email",
      "name" => "email",
      "name" => "email",
      "name" => "email",
      "name" => "email",
      "name" => "email",
  ];
  foreach ($users as $key => $val) {
      drush_invoke("user-create", $val);
      drush_print("Created account for email " . $val);
      drush_set_option("password", $key);
      drush_invoke('user-password', $val); 
      drush_print("Created password for email " . $val . " with password " . $key);
      drush_set_option("mail", $val);
      drush_invoke('user-add-role', "Premium members");
      drush_print("Added premium role to " . $val);
  }
?>
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: @YPCrumble Can you double check that you're using the right role name (machine name, not the title)? And the role already exists (`role-create`)? Probably you've to pass extra argument for `user-add-role` command to specify the username (`$key`).

Answer (score 3):

If you are having trouble with `drush_invoke`, try `drush_invoke_process`, which has two advantages over `drush_invoke`:

1. It is executed in a separate process, so you can set options explicitly, and do not need to worry about option "pollution" from previous calls to `drush_set_option()`
2. The results of the operation, including all log messages, is returned as structured php data, so you have a better idea of what was done.

Example:

```
$values = drush_invoke_process("@self", "user-add-role", array("Premium members"), array('mail' => $val));
```

You will find the output of the command in `$values['output']`, and structured results (if available) in `$values['object']`.

Note that in general, there is nothing wrong with calling `drush_invoke` as you are doing above; you may use that technique if it works for your use case. It is likely to be faster, but may sometimes be fragile.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way better way of using `drush` to achieve this and that is using [drush php-script](http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/php-script/):

```
$ drush scr /path/to/create-users.php
```

Create `create-users.php` and put it somewhere:

```
<?php
/* 
 * Content of create-users.php (could be located anywhere on the system)
 */

$users = array(
    'name1' => 'name1@domain',
    'name2' => 'name2@domain',
    // ...
);    
$role_name = 'Premium members';

$role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name);
foreach ($users as $name => $email) {
  //set up the user fields
  $fields = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'mail' => $email,
    'pass' => user_password(),
    'status' => 1,
    'roles' => array(
        $role->rid => $role->name,
    ),
  );
  //the first parameter is left blank so a new user is created
  $account = user_save('', $fields);
}
```

(Code snippet from http://codekarate.com/blog/create-user-account-drupal-7-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've omitted the `$val` in your user-add-role invoke.

Drush won't know which user to add the role to!

You have

```
drush_invoke('user-add-role', "Premium members");
```

You should have

```
drush_invoke('user-add-role', "Premium members", $val);
```

If that doesn't solve it, you next might need to check the handling of role name, since it contains a space. A quick test (`drush user-add-role 'Some role' user@example.com`) locally suggests that this should work OK if the Drush command gets the parameter with the space in it.

As far as *"Is there a better way to achieve this?"* goes, yes - you could be checking the results of each command and reporting back failures, rather than moving on to the next step. (If the user account already exists when you call `drush user-create`, your code may want to stop before changing the password for an existing account with `drush user-password`.)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option, particularly handy when you many need to rerun with new users/updates, is to use [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds). Then upload/point to a CSV.